# Android Mystery: Text Disappearing in random TextView

Tags: android, gridview

I have a problem in my application [Life Gallery](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=myownlife.pigeau&hl=fr). In this application, I have a fragment that displays the user's media directory in a gridView. Here is a screenshot :

[image: screen shot]

As you can see, each directory is represented with an ImageView and a TextView, this latter containing the name of the directory. If you check the third line, you will see that the text of two TextView are empty...This is my bug. The elements of my gridview that present such a bug varies if I scroll or if rotate my phone...

Here is my layout for an element of the gridView :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_global"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="1dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/directory_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_album_imageview" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/directory_text"
    style="@style/Act_MyOwnLife_TextView_large"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/directory_image"
    android:background="@color/black_transparent"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:singleLine="true" 
     />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the code for my Adapter, focusing on the function getView:

```
   @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = this.activity.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_directory_gridview, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.layout_global);
            viewHolder.textViewDirectory = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.directory_text);
            viewHolder.imageViewDirectory = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.directory_image);


            view.setTag(R.id.viewHolder, viewHolder);
        }else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag(R.id.viewHolder);
        }

        viewHolder.relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(this.viewFragmentDirectory.layoutParams);
        viewHolder.imageViewDirectory.setTag(position);
        viewHolder.imageViewDirectory.setImageBitmap(null);
        viewHolder.position = position;

        ModelDirectoryAndMedia directoryAndImage =this.directoriesAndMedias.get(position);

        viewHolder.textViewDirectory.setText(directoryAndImage.directoryView);

        ImageView imageView = viewHolder.imageViewDirectory;
        // creation/retrieve the thumbnail with a thread
        job = new Job(imageView, 
                directoryAndImage.media, Options.OPTIONS_THUMBNAIL, 
                position);
        this.bitmapCreate.addJobThumbnail(job);

        return view;
    }
```

What I did to find the bug :

- I check that my String was not empty when I call "viewHolder.textViewDirectory.setText(s);"
- I try to check with hierarchyViewer, but I can not browse an element if the TextView is empty...I do not know why...
- I remove the transparency of the background, remove the background property of the textView, I set "ImageView.setImageBitmap(null);" to check that it was not due to the ImageView...

But without success...the bug was still here...

After more test, I found the reason of the bug: it is due to this line of code in the getView method :

```
viewHolder.relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(this.viewFragmentDirectory.layoutPara‌​ms);
```

I use this line to display the empty ImageView to the correct size. So that when the thumbnail is ready, the insertion in the ImageView will not change its size ( the settings of my LayoutParams is done with the size of my thumbnail )

Any idea ? any comments on my code ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Ok....the bug is due to this line of code in the getView method : "viewHolder.relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(this.viewFragmentDirectory.layoutParams);" But why ?

Comment: In fact, my problem is that the thumbnails are loaded by a thread, so that the width and height of each gridView element is not known, and so the final size of the gridview is again not known...that is why I use this line "viewHolder.relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(this.viewFragmentDirectory.layoutParams);" to indicate to the gridview the size of each element. If I do not do this solution, I have a strange bug : the last line of my gridView is not visible at the first time...But if I use my solution, some textView does not appear...any help ?

Comment: Well the fact that you asynchronously load the thumbnails is not why you set layout params. try simplifying your use case to find the source of the problem. If I were you i'd first replace all images with a static one, made all texts be the same "hello world" and removed the layout params setting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to explain in my previous comment, why I must do the "set layout". If I remove it, all the textviews would be correctly displayed. I tested it. But I will get another bug due to the use of the thread.  The problem of the not displayed textView is precisely due to do the "set layout" call with a parameter fixing the width and height to specific values...(I use specific values because I know the size of my thumbnail - and so each imageView is first displayed with the correct size and a gray background, waiting just for the thumbnail)

Comment: I think your real problem is an issue with threading. You should load the image asynchronously, having a placeholder instead of the real thumbnail until it loads. There are quite a few guides on how to do that. This is what I would go about doing if I were you.

Comment: No it is not due to the thread. I already test my fragment without displaying the thumbnail and I also obtained the invisible textView....very strange....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok...The bug was due to the call to :

```
viewHolder.relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(this.viewFragmentDirectory.layoutParams);
```

But I do not understand why...anyway, I did this to ensure that my ImageView had the correct initial size to display the thumbnail, loaded by a thread.

So I found an other solution to set a minimum size to the ImageView even if they are empty :

```
viewHolder.imageView.setMinimumHeight(this.viewControlerAlbum.sizeThumbnail);
viewHolder.imageView.setMinimumWidth(this.viewControlerAlbum.sizeThumbnail);
```

My layout.xml file is a bit updated :

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_album_imageview"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

I added the adjustViewBounds attribute.